# Installing newer driver to current kernel

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, kernel, intel-wireless

I have problems with my notebook's wifi (Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59) on Ubuntu 14.04 (3.13.0-68-generic). Signal is shown often low (for no reason and same notebooks in Windows have much better performance) even though I am standing next to the router.

A friend of mine installed on his notebook (identical model brand etc...) Debian and it works perfectly. I asked him to send me `modinfo iwlwifi` output.

It seems to be, he has a newer driver and kernel version.
Then I used diff to compare to mine. Should I try to install the new module (driver) on my current kernel or try to use newer kernel, which is not provided yet by the Ubuntu repositories? I do not want to play around with the kernel without any advice from experienced users and mess up my system.

> 1c1
>
> < filename:
>   /lib/modules/**3.13.0-68-generic**/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
>
> ---
>
> > filename:       /lib/modules/**3.16.0-4-amd64**/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
>
> 3c3
>
> < author:         **Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation**
>
> ---
>
> > author:         **Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation**
>
> 18,21c18,24
>
> < firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-7.ucode
>
> < firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
>
> < firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
>
> < srcversion:     A45BAACCAD263355629DB7A
>
> ---
>
> > firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
>
> > firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
>
> > firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
>
> > firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode
>
> > srcversion:     3E4DCD8265C8E43DCA7B0EA
>
> > alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F4sv*sd00000030bc*sc*i*
>
> > alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000010bc*sc*i*
>
> 300,303c303
>
> < vermagic:       3.13.0-68-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
>
> < signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
>
> < sig_key:        xxx
>
> < sig_hashalgo:   sha512
>
> ---
>
> > vermagic:       3.16.0-4-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions
>
> 309c309
>
> < parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer
>   0=system default, 1=disable, 2=enable (default: 0) (int)
>
> ---
>
> > parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable (default: 1) (int)
>
> 310a311
>
> > parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
>
> 314a316
>
> > parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

Comment: Check out this link 》https://www.quora.com/How-do-we-update-kernel-in-Ubuntu-by-command-line-in-terminal

Comment: Thanks, I have found such solutions on the net but I would really like to know, if I can avoid it by simply and only installing new module on the standard kernel release for Ubuntu?

Comment: I would not recommend changing your kenel please check out mu answer here http://askubuntu.com/a/707042/459037

Comment: Thanks, so this was also my impression but I wasn't sure. I am going to try to upgrade module only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be it is highly **un**recommended to upgrade kernel beyond what is provided by the Ubuntu repositories. And it is fairly simple to upgrade a single module with **Backports**. Backports are simply kernel modules provided by the Backports team of linux. [Here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/) you can find packages from various versions of the kernel and compile. Specifically, for the iwlwifi, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608983/verisons-of-iwlwifi-and-firmware-for-my-wireless-card) is a solution, which most likely also works for other modules. So far my wifi has been working without drops.